# How to scroll synchronization like "switching"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The synchronized scrolling in my search was smooth [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/2brahp0m/).

But I want to sync scroll like switch.

[image: like this]

In this way, elements switches by every one scroll.
What I want to do is for each scroll, the right sentence chunk is highlighted & the left image is also switched.
How can I implement?

---

### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/von4zu1h/)
↑ Here is the current situation.

↓ This is just code. It doesn't work properly because the swiper could not be inserted. Look at JSFiddle.

```js
/*var swiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
        clickable: 'true',
      },
      keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      mousewheel: {
        forceToAxis: true,
        invert: true,
});*/
```

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  padding: 0 0 0 2.4rem;
}
.right {
  padding: 0 4.7rem 0 6.5rem;
  position: relative;
}


.swiper-pagination {
  top: 6rem;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 69.3rem;
  height: 49.6rem;
}
.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper-slide img {
  width: 69.3rem;
}


.mai {
  margin: 2.8rem 0 0 0;
  height: 37.8rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style:none;
}

.main-p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="left">
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <section class="swiper-wrapper imgs">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="https://placehold.jp/45/050da6/ffffff/693x496.png?text=1" height="496" /></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="https://placehold.jp/45/a60550/ffffff/693x496.png?text=2" /></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="https://placehold.jp/45/0591a6/ffffff/693x496.png?text=3" /></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="https://placehold.jp/45/a6a105/ffffff/693x496.png?text=4" /></div>
  </section>
</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
<div class="mai">
  <section class="main-p">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
    <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```